# TS pattern for library plugins

Tags: typescript

I maintain a few plugins for various JS libraries, which hold reference to the library instance. I prefer to write them with JSDoc, to get benefits of TS type checking in plain JS. I'm looking a better pattern how to structure such plugins, so that it works well with TS type checking. This question is not specific to any library, Cytoscape.js is used only as an example. Consider the following code:

```js
class CytoscapePlugin {
  /** @type cytoscape.Core */
  cy;

  /** @type boolean */
  originalZoomEnabled;

  constructor(cy) {
    this.cy = cy;

    this.originalZoomEnabled = this.cy.zoomEnabled();
    this.cy.zoomEnabled(false);
  }

  fit() {
    this.cy.fit();
  }

  destroy() {
    this.cy.zoomEnabled(this.originalZoomEnabled);
    
    this.cy = undefined;
  }
}
```

When initializing the plugin, it stores a reference to the library object, because it needs to call its methods later on. Also, it configures library behavior necessary for the plugin.

When the plugin is not needed anymore, there is a `destroy` method to be called. It reverts the library behavior back to the original state, and clears the library reference, to make the plugin instance unusable, in case a developer-user uses the plugin by mistake after it was destroyed.

Also, clearing out the library reference might be helpful for garbage collection. I'm not sure if it's necessary after I unregister all registered event handlers, but it's important to be sure that the library instance is not blocked from GC in any case.

However, obviously setting the library reference to `undefined` fails TS type checking, because it is not declared to allow `undefined`. If I allow it with `cytoscape.Core | undefined`, then I'd have to check its value before using it in every other method (`fit`). Technically, `undefined` is an invalid state, so I'd like to avoid it in the type definition.

How would you recommend to structure such plugins, so that it works well with TS type checking? I'm looking for an idiomatic TS pattern, which avoids type overrides, and minimizes the boilerplate of checking if the plugin is active in every method.

---

Links to some of my affected packages:

- https://github.com/zakjan/leaflet-lasso
- https://github.com/zakjan/cytoscape-lasso
- https://github.com/zakjan/cytoscape-mapbox-gl
- https://github.com/zakjan/pixi-graph

Comment: You could have a private `getInstance` method used instead of `this.cy` that throws an error when attempting to call `fit` after `destroy`. This way eliminating the risk of calling `cy` when it is undefined, making the compiler happy, and at the same time tell developers that they incidentally did something wrong.